# How to populate a parent table value using child table trigger

Tags: oracle

Workorder table(Parent) with ID and Status.
Child workorder with ID, ChildID

I have to populate the value of ID, ChildID and status to a new table when ever there is INSERT in data in the child table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why to you need two tables to store same data, you could do this with one. If i understood right you need something like this:

```
--Main table
CREATE TABLE "WORKORDER" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL, 
      "ParentID"  NUMBER(*,0), 
      "Status" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
   );

--Constraint pk
ALTER TABLE "WORKORDER" ADD (
  CONSTRAINT "WORKORDER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"));

--Sequence
CREATE SEQUENCE "WORK_SEQ"
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

--Trigger for sequence
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "WORK_ID_TRIGGER"
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON "WORKORDER"
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT WORK_SEQ.nextval 
  INTO :new."ID" 
  FROM DUAL;
END;

--Another table
CREATE TABLE "ANOTHER" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL, 
      "ParentID"  NUMBER(*,0), 
      "Status" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
   );

--Thirgger on child record inser populate another table.
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AFTER_CHILD_INSERT"
AFTER INSERT
ON "WORKORDER"
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
  IF (:new."ParentID" IS NOT NULL)
  THEN 
  INSERT INTO ANOTHER VALUES 
  (:new."ID", :new."ParentID", :new."Status"); 
  END IF;
END;
```